# Поисковый движок sphinx

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно почитать о том, как установить sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) на хостинг. И вообще, возможно ли это для любого хостинга? У нас unix хостинг masterhost. Необходимо реализовать поиск с учетом морфологии русского языка и вывод результатов с учетом релевантности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смешно, но это было моей первой рабочей задачей в качестве программиста.
На юникс и бсд ставиться из репозиториев и портов соответственно.
Этот момент уточните у того, кто вашу ОС настраивал или у хостера.
Вот те ссылки, которые я считаю полезными.
[Как поставить.](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/installing.html)
[Как поставить в русском варианте](http://livestreet.ru/blog/dev_documentation/366.html)
Как настроить
[Официальная документация](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/)
[Примеры работы с движком](http://habrahabr.ru/post/104690/)
[Ещё пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131089/)
[И ещё](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132118/)
[И это](http://selikoff.ru/webmaster/bistriy_poisk/)
ИМХО любой грамотный программист со времен в этой штуке сможет разобраться.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Правда, наш хостер ответил, что поставить sphinx нам невозможно, не уточняла, почему.

Answer (score -3):

Чувствую, с вашими навыками, данный модуль будет крайне проблематично поставить. Нужен специалист. Также скажу, что не для любого хостинга. Тут нужно обговаривать уже с самим хостером.

Comment: Спасибо. А специалист нужен - сисадмин?

Comment: Программист конечно :) Сисадмин с железками возится.

Comment: У меня стоит задача - организовать поиск по БД с учетом морфологии русского языка и выводом результатов по релевантности. Может, можно ее решить как-то более простыми способами?

Comment: Советую посмотреть, что есть в интернете по запросу: "поиск по БД с учетом морфологии". Я вот что нашел: http://notes.rudomilov.ru/2007/08/16/poisk-s-russkoy-morfologiey-sredstvami-php/